# iteratively key shape keys only on active object

Tags: python, shape-keys

I need to keyframe shape keys and have a script that's nicely working -

```
import bpy


frames = bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1


for frame in range(frames):
    for shapekey in bpy.data.shape_keys:
        for i, keyblock in enumerate(shapekey.key_blocks):
            if keyblock.name != 'Basis':
               curr = i - 1
               if curr != frame:
                   keyblock.value = 0
                   keyblock.keyframe_insert("value", frame=frame)
               else:
                   keyblock.value = 1
                   keyblock.keyframe_insert("value", frame=frame)
```

The issue is, I need it to work only on the active object, not every object in the scene.

Anyone any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do?

```
import bpy

frames = bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1

# For the active object...
ob = bpy.context.active_object
me = ob.data

# Remove ['Basis'] from a shallow copy of *ob's* shape-keys list.
kblocks = dict(me.shape_keys.key_blocks)
del kblocks['Basis']

# Keyframe shapekeys' values to 1 for the frame corresponding
# to their position in remaining list, 0 for other frames
for f in range(frames):
    for i, kb in enumerate(kblocks):
        kblocks[kb].value = (f == i)
        kblocks[kb].keyframe_insert("value", frame=f)
```

This may get burned down by a proper Pythonista.. :)

Comment: Perfect! :) Thank you for helping out!  Still getting used to Blender API as well as python.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the other way around.

```
import bpy

End_Frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_end
ob = bpy.context.active_object
me = ob.data

kblocks = me.shape_keys.key_blocks
l = len(kblocks)

for a in range(1,l):  # This can point your specific shapkey
    kblocks[a].value = 0
    kblocks[a].keyframe_insert("value", frame=End_Frame - 3)
    kblocks[a].value = 1
    kblocks[a].keyframe_insert("value", frame=End_Frame)
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/153942)